# Firemonkey: How to define a component that contain another component?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Under Delphi, i want to create a new firemonkey control that will contain another firemonkey control. This is not really a problem because i can do like this :

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBtn := Trectangle.create(self);
  FBtn.parent := self;
  FBtn.stored := false;
end;
```

But now i would like to permit end-user to modifie the properties of the FBtn in the **Object Inspector** also! i don't know how to do :(

if i remove the FBtn.stored := False then i will have in the structure explorer some component with name like < Components[7] > and every time i will do view the form as text and back to view as form then a new component will appear in the structure explorer :(

Comment: Try to add FBtn.SetSubcomponent(true) in TMyComponent.Create. Works fine in vcl, should work in firemonkey, too if they are not very crazy...

Comment: not it's change nothing, if i do FBtn.SetSubcomponent‌​(true) i will still have strange component name in the Structure explorer :( in some way FBtn.SetSubcomponent‌​(true) work like FBtn.Stored ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Remy's answer technically will work, I wouldn't consider it the appropriate approach. This is because when you publish any `TComponent` descendant as a property, this presumes that you would create such a control *externally* and then assign it within the object inspector. Surely you don't want to allow this to happen, since this control is created *internally*. You also presumably only want to allow the user to change *certain* properties, not all of them.

Instead, I would recommend using a `TPersistent` which exposes only those properties of the control you actually want to provide access to.

```
unit MyComponentUnit;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils,
  Fmx.Controls, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TMyComponentButton = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FBtn: TRectangle;
    function GetXRadius: Single;
    function GetYRadius: Single;
    procedure SetXRadius(const Value: Single);
    procedure SetYRadius(const Value: Single);
    //And any other property getters/setters you wish to wrap
  public
    constructor Create(ABtn: TRectangle);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property XRadius: Single read GetXRadius write SetXRadius;
    property YRadius: Single read GetYRadius write SetYRadius;
    //And any other properties you wish to wrap
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TControl)
  private
    FBtn: TRectangle;
    FMyComponentButton: TMyComponentButton;
    procedure SetMyComponentButton(const Value: TMyComponentButton);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property MyComponentButton: TMyComponentButton
      read FMyComponentButton write SetMyComponentButton;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyComponentButton }

constructor TMyComponentButton.Create(ABtn: TRectangle);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBtn:= ABtn;
end;

destructor TMyComponentButton.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponentButton.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TMyComponentButton then begin
    XRadius:= (Source as TMyComponentButton).XRadius;
    YRadius:= (Source as TMyComponentButton).YRadius;
    //And everything else you need to assign
  end else
    inherited;
end;

function TMyComponentButton.GetXRadius: Single;
begin
  Result:= FBtn.XRadius;
end;

function TMyComponentButton.GetYRadius: Single;
begin
  Result:= FBtn.YRadius;
end;

procedure TMyComponentButton.SetXRadius(const Value: Single);
begin
  FBtn.XRadius:= Value;
end;

procedure TMyComponentButton.SetYRadius(const Value: Single);
begin
  FBtn.YRadius:= Value;
end;

{ TMyComponent }

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBtn:= TRectangle.Create(Self);
  FBtn.Parent:= Self;
  FBtn.Stored:= False;
  FMyComponentButton:= TMyComponentButton.Create(FBtn);
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FMyComponentButton);
  FreeAndNil(FBtn);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyComponentButton(const Value: TMyComponentButton);
begin
  FMyComponentButton.Assign(Value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your `TMyComponentButton` class does not implement `Assign()`.

Comment: @remy yeah, that's up to op to decide how to implement. Just laying the base concept.

Comment: the least you could do is show how to implement it for the properties you created.

Comment: A property doesn't have to expose an external class. Think of TFont etc.

Comment: isn't it possible to expose (via property) a subclass of the component in which subclass you unpublish (move to public or protected) the properties you don't wish to expose?

Comment: to answer my own comment/question above, it seems you can't unpublish properties without using "UnlistPublishedProperty" - https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/tip-removing-a-property-at-design-time/

Answer (score 4):

Anything you want to expose in the Objct Inspector must be declared in a `published` property, eg:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBtn: TRectangle;
    procedure SetBtn(Value: TRectangle);
  published
    property Btn: TRectangle read FBtn write SetBtn;
  end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBtn := TRectangle.create(Self);
  FBtn.Parent := Self;
  FBtn.Stored := False;
  FBtn.SetSubComponent(True);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetBtn(Value: TRectangle);
begin
  FBtn.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Comment: thanks it's work !! just one remak in the object inspector i have the name like *MyComponent1.* ... is possible to have a name like *MyComponent1.button1* instead for exemple ? this is not really important anyway

Comment: @loki what you describe does not make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: remy, i know what i want to say, with your method (that look exactly what i want), if i go on the event tab and try to add an event to the subcomponent i receive "Cannot create a method for an unnamed component" :(

Comment: Of course not, because the subcomponent's `Name` property has not been assigned a value. You really shouldn't be exposing the subcomponent's events to users. The main component should assign its own handlers to the subcomponent's events, and then the main component can expose its own events for users.