# How to avoid duplicate image when rotated in Firemonkey component?

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey

### What did I do?

I'm trying to develop a FMX Gauge component. For the time being it has only a needle. I've created a new Package and added the following code:
    unit FMX.VDO;

```
interface

uses
    System.SysUtils,
    System.Classes,
    FMX.Types,
    FMX.Controls,
    FMX.MultiResBitmap,
    FMX.Layouts,
    FMX.Objects;

type
    TVdoLayout = class(TScaledLayout)
    private        
        FNeedle    : TImage;

        function GetBitMapNeedle: TFixedMultiResBitmap;        
        procedure SetBitMapNeedle(const Value: TFixedMultiResBitmap);
        function GetValue: Double;
        procedure SetValue(const Value: Double);        
        { Private declarations }

    protected
        { Protected declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    published
        { Published declarations }        
        property BitMapNeedle    : TFixedMultiResBitmap read GetBitMapNeedle write SetBitMapNeedle;
        property Value           : Double read GetValue write SetValue;
    end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterComponents('Samples', [TVdoLayout]);
end;

{ TVdoLayout }

constructor TVdoLayout.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited;
    Self.Size.Width  := 326;
    Self.Size.Height := Self.Size.Width;

    FNeedle                  := TImage.Create(Self);
    FNeedle.Parent           := Self;
    FNeedle.Width            := 262;
    FNeedle.Height           := 21;
    FNeedle.Position.X       := 40;
    FNeedle.Position.Y       := 270;
    FNeedle.Height           := Self.Height * 0.04901;
    FNeedle.Width            := Self.Width * 0.7485;
    FNeedle.RotationCenter.X := 0.935;
    FNeedle.RotationCenter.Y := 0.27;

    FNeedle.RotationAngle := 45;
end;    

function TVdoLayout.GetBitMapNeedle: TFixedMultiResBitmap;
begin
    Result := FNeedle.MultiResBitmap;
end;

procedure TVdoLayout.SetBitMapNeedle(const Value: TFixedMultiResBitmap);
begin    
    FNeedle.MultiResBitmap := Value;
end;

function TVdoLayout.GetValue: Double;
begin
    Result := FNeedle.RotationAngle;
end;    

procedure TVdoLayout.SetValue(const Value: Double);
begin    
    FNeedle.RotationAngle := Value;    
end;

end.
```

After this I've build the project and installed my component.

I've created a new FMX project and put my component. I load a picture of a needle in design time. See below:

[image: Needle design time]

At design time I can change the property `Value`. If you see the code above, `Value` changes `RotationAngle` of the needle. It works perfectly at design time.

### What's the problem?

In run time, when I change the `Value` property of my component through TEdit to 90 it works, but a snapshot of the initial needle is taken, and it seems duplicate as can be seen below:

[image: Needle run time]

### Other things that I've tried without success?

I've tried to call resize and repaint functions.
Also added `FNeedle.SetSubComponent(True);` during Create as @UweRaabe suggested.
If I load the needle image at run time it works. But this is not a desirable solution.

### Details

- Delphi 10.1 Berlin
- FireMonkey (on Windows)

Comment: You are probably tricked by the streaming system. Does it work when you add _FNeedle.SetSubComponent(True)_ during Create?

Comment: @UweRaabe No, it doesn't.

Comment: In that case please provide a minimal project showing the error.

Comment: @UweRaabe, I reformulated my question. I think now it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: When you made the test with SetSubComponent, did you re-create your DFM or did you test with the existing one?

Comment: @UweRaabe, Yes, I re-create my DFM. I never do test with the existing one. I delete the component of my test project, so I edit my component and do a Build command. Only then I return to my test project and add the component again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my searches I found the solution here: [Firemonkey: How to define a component that contain another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985078/firemonkey-how-to-define-a-component-that-contain-another-component)

I have just to set the property `Stored` as `False`. See below:

```
FNeedle.Stored := false;
```