# FMX: dropping selfmade component on form duplicates subcomponents

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I created my own progressbar (TProgressBalken) consisting of a TRectangle, within that there's another TRectangle (a) with a different color, its width varies with the progress value (0..100). Finally a Tlabel sits on top of it displaying the current value as text.
All works fine when creating this component at runtime.

When dropping this on a new multidevice form (IDE set to 32-bit windows) it also works fine.
But when switching IDE to Android, TRectangle(a) and Label are duplicated in the fmx file, I see now the label painted twice. And Delphi complains of duplicated items.

Originally I assigned no name to TRectangle(a) and Label, but Delphi complained, so I assigned names during creation, but the actual problem remains.

Any idea what is missing?

This is my component:

```
unit ProgressBalken;

interface
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.UITypes,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Objects;

type
  TProgressBalken = class(TRectangle)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BalkenUpdate;
    procedure SizeUpdate;
    procedure SetValue(v: integer);
    procedure SetUnits(v: string);
    procedure SetBalkenColor(v: TAlphaColor);
    function  GetBalkenColor: TAlphaColor;
    procedure aResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Balken: TRectangle;
    labelx: Tlabel;
    fValue: integer;
    funits: string;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

  published
    property Value: integer read fValue write SetValue;
    property ValueUnits: string read fUnits write SetUnits;
    property BalkenColor: TAlphaColor read GetBalkenColor write SetBalkenColor; // stored IsColorStored;
  end;

  procedure Register;

implementation
uses
windows, System.Math;

constructor TProgressBalken.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  width:=100;
  height:= 40;
  fValue:= 1;
  fUnits:= '';
  Parent:= TForm(AOwner);
  Fill.Color:= System.UITypes.TAlphaColorRec.red; //Null;
  Balken:= TRectangle.Create(self);
  Balken.Parent:= self;
  Balken.Position.X:= 0;
  Balken.Position.Y:= 0; ;
  Balken.Fill.Color:= System.UITypes.TAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
  Balken.name:= 'balken'+name;
  labelx:= Tlabel.Create(self);
  labelx.Parent:= Balken;
  labelx.name:= 'labelx'+name;
  OnResize:= aResize;
  SizeUpdate;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.aResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SizeUpdate;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Balken.Free;
  labelx.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.SizeUpdate;
var
 h, y: single;
begin
  Balken.Height:= Height;
  Balken.Width:= Width;
  h:= System.Math.min(40, Height);
  labelx.StyledSettings:= labelx.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Size];
  if h>20 then
    labelx.TextSettings.Font.Size:= round(0.5 * h)
  else
    labelx.TextSettings.Font.Size:= round(0.7 * h);
  y:= (height / 2) - (labelx.TextSettings.Font.Size / 2) -2;
  labelx.Position.Y:= System.Math.max(-5, y);
  labelx.Position.X:=  Width / 4;
  BalkenUpdate;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.BalkenUpdate;
begin
  Balken.Width:= fValue / 100 *(width - 2*Balken.Position.x);
  labelx.Text:= IntToStr(fValue) +' ' +fUnits;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.SetValue(v: integer);
var i: integer;
begin
  v:= System.Math.max(v, -1);
  fValue:= System.Math.min(v, 100);
  BalkenUpdate;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.SetUnits(v: string);
begin
  fUnits:= v;
  SetValue(fValue);
end;

function TProgressBalken.GetBalkenColor: TAlphaColor;
begin
 result:= Balken.Fill.Color;
end;

procedure TProgressBalken.SetBalkenColor(v: TAlphaColor);
begin
  Balken.Fill.Color:= v;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('3s_Spezielles', [TProgressBalken]);
end;

initialization
  RegisterFmxClasses([TProgressBalken]);

end.
```

This is the fmx after dropping my component TProgressBalken
IDE is set to 32-Bit Windows

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 3
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 56.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 168.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object ProgressBalken1: TProgressBalken
    Fill.Color = claRed
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 64.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Value = 1
    BalkenColor = claAqua
    object balken: TRectangle
      Fill.Color = claAqua
      Size.Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object labelx: TLabel
        StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
        Position.X = 25.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
        TextSettings.Font.Size = 20.000000000000000000
        Text = '1 '
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the fmx after setting IDE to Android
object 'balken' is now inserted twice

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 56.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 168.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object ProgressBalken1: TProgressBalken
    Fill.Color = claRed
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 64.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Value = 1
    BalkenColor = claAqua
    object balken: TRectangle
      Fill.Color = claAqua
      Size.Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object labelx: TLabel
        StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
        Position.X = 25.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
        TextSettings.Font.Size = 20.000000000000000000
        Text = '1 '
      end
    end
    object balken: TRectangle
      Fill.Color = claAqua
      Size.Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object labelx: TLabel
        StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
        Position.X = 25.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
        TextSettings.Font.Size = 20.000000000000000000
        Text = '1 '
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FMX, for any sub-component that you create in a constructor so it is available at design-time and to DFM streaming, you need to set the component's `Stored` property to False, as well as call `SetSubComponent()` on it, eg:

```
constructor TProgressBalken.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  Balken := TRectangle.Create(self);
  Balken.SetSubComponent(True);
  Balken.Stored := False;
  ...
  labelx := Tlabel.Create(self);
  labelx.SetSubComponent(True);
  labelx.Stored := False;
  ...
end;
```

See [Firemonkey: How to define a component that contain another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985078/)

Comment: many thanks, that now works. I was not aware of SetSubComponent and Stored, both are required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call SetSubComponent(True) on your two sub-components:

```
constructor TProgressBalken.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  width:=100;
  height:= 40;
  fValue:= 1;
  fUnits:= '';
  Parent:= TForm(AOwner);
  Fill.Color:= System.UITypes.TAlphaColorRec.red; //Null;
  Balken:= TRectangle.Create(self);
  Balken.SetSubComponent(True);
  Balken.Parent:= self;
  Balken.Position.X:= 0;
  Balken.Position.Y:= 0; ;
  Balken.Fill.Color:= System.UITypes.TAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
  Balken.name:= 'balken'+name;
  labelx:= Tlabel.Create(self);
  labelx.SetSubComponent(True);
  labelx.Parent:= Balken;
  labelx.name:= 'labelx'+name;
  OnResize:= aResize;
  SizeUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: I also needed .Stored := False, without that I still got problems.